# Logo animation like this? ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to do in actionscript 3 an animation like [this](http://foros.cristalab.com/actionscript-3-flex-y-air-f40/)

Does anyone know how?

thanks in advance.

(Solved) --> [Here](http://arcadespain.info/infoRetos) you can see the result.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think "how do I do this random thing on the internet" is a suitable question - did you have a go at it and get stuck somewhere perhaps?

Comment: what have you tried so far? do you know how to rotate an object in actionscript already? If you know the basics, take a look at the TweenLite or TweenMax libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [TweenLite](http://greensock.com/tweenlite-as) library. It make possible to easely make different animations. For your case you can try (with some custom properties in Elastic ease):

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;
TweenLite.to(mc, 1, {rotation:360, ease:Elastic.easeOut});
```

Try demo with different tweens by the link above.

Comment: Thanks very nuch!

At the end, I've used the next:

    TweenMax.to(logoArcade, 3, {transformAroundCenter:{rotation:360}, ease:Circ.easeInOut});

Thanks